# Dropdown does not open after adding MDdatatable in kivy app

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to create a simple kivy app with just one dropdown and one data table (MDDatatable). The dropdown works fine until I add the MDdatatable. After adding MDMDatatable the dropdown does not open.

This is the full code with MDdatatable and dropdown added. The dropdown does not open for this one -

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button


my_screen = """
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            title: 'test app'

        FloatLayout:
            id:s1
            Button:
                id:button2
                text: "button1"
                size_hint:  (.1, .1)
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.9}
"""


class Test(MDApp):
        def build(self):

            screen = Builder.load_string(my_screen)

            data_table = MDDataTable(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
                                 size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
                                 rows_num=10,
                                 column_data=[
                                     ("col1", dp(20)),
                                     ("col2", dp(20)),
                                     ("col3", dp(20)),
                                     ("col4", dp(20))
                                 ],
                                 )

            screen.add_widget(data_table)
            


            self.dropdown2 = DropDown()
            for index in range(2, 5):

                btn = Button(text='%d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
                btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown2.select(btn.text))
                self.dropdown2.add_widget(btn)

            screen.ids.button2.bind(on_release=self.dropdown2.open)    
            self.dropdown2.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(screen.ids.button2, 'text', x))



            return(screen)
Test().run()
```

However, if I remove the MDDatatable, the dropdown works fine -

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button


my_screen = """
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            title: 'test app'

        FloatLayout:
            id:s1
            Button:
                id:button2
                text: "button1"
                size_hint:  (.1, .1)
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.9}
"""


class Test(MDApp):
        def build(self):

            screen = Builder.load_string(my_screen)

    
            self.dropdown2 = DropDown()
            for index in range(2, 5):

                btn = Button(text='%d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
                btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown2.select(btn.text))
                self.dropdown2.add_widget(btn)

            screen.ids.button2.bind(on_release=self.dropdown2.open)    
            self.dropdown2.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(screen.ids.button2, 'text', x))



            return(screen)
Test().run()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `MDDataTable` is an extension of `ModalView`, which means that you cannot interact with the rest of the App while the `MDDataTable` is in play.

Answer (score 0):

So I am developing a KivyMD app too and had this same issue - in fact, I am still facing it. In short, KivyMD's, as the other comment is suggesting, inherits from ModalView. In other words, it is considered a pop up or basically like a permanent dialogue box. In other words, whilst the MDDataTable is on screen, you cannot interact with any other widgets by intentional design.

I recommend looking on the GitHub page where the original developer(s) often respond and I believe someone actually came up with an alternative to use instead of ModalView that, although they were not using that solution to fix this problem, probably would fix it.

I have not found that part of the GitHub page again though since my last google search but I am currently trying to find it!

It would require going into your Python files, finding the KivyMD library folder, going into the uix directory, opening up datatables.py, editing it and hoping it still works.

Somethings I would bear in mind - KivyMD simply just uses Kivy and then puts extra widgets on top. This means you can use normal kivy widgets so you could find someone else's table they have made and use that instead. Moreover, KivyMD, if I remember rightly, is still in alpha stages of development and is very far from completion, so it is quite rough around the edges and they are still testing for things like this and will probably fix it soon as this feature, if people, when developing apps using DataTables, don't test their app thoroughly enough, they won't be able to use it so they will probably get more complaints. One final thing, DataTables are probably the least developed widget so far and, on the docs, it even says to just be aware of this when using them.

Just before I send this, I did a quick google search and actually have found the github pages I was on about! The bottom one in particular is a closed case which discusses how to "fix it". I think they sum it up perfectly by saying that you are allowed to edit how each code works on your own machine and, at the end of the day, if it breaks, you can just copy and paste the original code into it and it will work again!

https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/596
https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/315